# The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' ?? Extracting arguments problem

Tags: flutter, dart

While extracting arguments from the route, in order to guarantee the null safety, I've put the bang '!' before settings as shown bellow :

```dart
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final routeArgs = 
     ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map<String, String>;
    final categoryId = routeArgs['id'];
    final categoryTitle = routeArgs['title'];
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(categoryTitle),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('The Recipes for the Category'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But when I wanted to display `categoryTitle` in the new screen (`title: Text(categoryTitle)`), I had a problem:

```
The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.
```

I created the PushNamed method as shown below :

I'm using  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

Answer (score -1):

Here is the problem, Flutter does not know if you passed the 'title' argument to the page, of course you did, but you need to tell flutter what to do in case you forget to pass it.

> argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Note the `?` after the first `String`, there is a difference between `String` and `String?`, `String` is a value that can be any number of characters, but `String?` is a value that can be any number of characters **or `null`**.

Take a look at this example:

```
bool a = true;
bool? b = true;

a = null; // error, a can't be null
b = null;

if (a) {
}

if (b) { // error, b could be null
  
}

if (a == true) { // no error, but unnecesary
}

if (b == true) { // necessary
}
```

So in your case, `categoryTitle` will be null if you forget to pass a value, there are two possible ways to solve this:

1. give a default value:

```
var categoryTitle = routeArgs['title'] ?? 'default';
```

So now `categoryTitle` will be 'default' if `routeArgs['title']` is `null`, so `categoryTitle` will never be null ever again.

2. use the bang operator

```
var categoryTitle = route['args']!;
```

the bang (`!`) operator tells dart that the value you are checking (in this case `route['args']`) will never be `null`, that means dart will throw an error if the value is `null`, but it won't complain otherwise, **This seems like your best option**

Comment: I got it and It worked for me. I appreciate you taking the time to answer my question, Thank you .